# How to view addresses previously shown by Bitcoin QT console

Tags: bitcoin-core, address

I want to be able to compare receive and change addresses that are provided by watch-only wallet providers like Specter and Electrum with Bitcoin Core (not something like Ian Coleman's tool). I already used the "getnewaddress" RPC a bunch of times when playing around, and I would like to start over so that there's not a huge gap between unused addresses. I would love to be able to either 1) start over at index 0, 2) get an address for a specific index, or 3) get a list of, say, 10 addresses for a wallet even if the address has no transactions associated with it yet.

I'm guessing that one solution could be related to the "deriveaddresses" command. I've had troubles with this command though; so if there's an answer to avoid this method, I'd prefer to go that route. If "deriveaddresses" is the only way, then I'll open up a separate question and close this one.

Thank you